# Build issue after updating from Angular 7 to Angular 8

Tags: angular, angular7, angular8

I recently updated a project from Angular 7 to Angular 8.  When I go to build to prod I'm now getting the following error.

> ERROR in app/app.component.ts:7:36 - error TS2307: Cannot find module
>   '@angular/router/src/router_module'. 7 import { routerNgProbeToken }
>   from "@angular/router/src/router_module";

I've gone into the app.component.ts file to take a look at what the problem is, and it says (similar to the build error) cannot find `@angular/router/src/router_module`.  I haven't touched this project for over a year and I'm struggling to resolve this one (also I'm not that experienced with Angular so that doesn't help either)

Any suggestions on how I might resolve this so that I can build again would be greatly apprecited.

Comment: have you re-installed the node modules by command `npm install`

Comment: Yes I did a full npm install already

Comment: please cross check you have followed all angular upgrade guide rules from [here](https://update.angular.io/#7.0:8.0)

Comment: Please provide us app.component.ts file code so we can have look into it

Answer (score 0):

Try this as your `import`:

> import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

Remove `/src/router_module` on the end of the path.